How to find out ahead of time which court a trial will be held in?
If I'm being sued or want to sue someone, I file a lawsuit in a county where it has personal and subject jurisdiction over the case. If a county has more than one trial court, how do I find out ahead of time (when I file or receive the complaint and summons) which city or exact address or name of the trial court that the trial will be held in?

Keep in mind that until a case is filed, there is often more than one trial court in which a suit could be filed, and the Plaintiff gets to choose.

@ohwilleke Doesn't it mean a case is filed when I received the complaint and summon? And in the summon, the address of the court is listed?

The Plaintiff has to choose a venue by the time that a summons is issued. But, until a case is filed, it can often be filed in more than one court. For example, you can file an employment discrimination case in either state or federal court, and may be able to file it either in the county of corporate headquarters or the county where the discrimination took place.

@ohwilleke Wait, if the address of the court in the summon is a trial or superior court and I've researched it and confirm it's a state court, then doesn't it mean the venue is in a state court? Also, how do I know if a court is for federal or state jurisdiction?

In state court, venue means the particular state court, typically a level of the court and a county. If you file in state court or if the summons is in state court, then it is in state court. The federal trial courts in the U.S. are called U.S. District Courts.

Summons literally summons you to the court, so it would list the address of the court (see the CA SUM-100 form). Alternatively you can look at the court's website.
Specific location depends on the judge assigned to the case, and once a hearing is set you'll receive a notice with the exact address (potentially even including a room) and time of the hearing.

Do you know if there will be a chance that the address in the summon will be different from the actual address of the hearing? If so, when does that usually happen?

There is a chance, but it depends on the court in which you've filed. It's entirely possible to file in one county court house, then get transferred to a different county court house, then to a Federal courthouse, then a different federal courthouse, and then back to the county again.

@bdb484 How could that happen? In what scenario?

See for example Trump's attempts to remove his cases from state courts to Federal jurisdiction in Georgia and New York, change of venue motions, case-load reshuffling within the county court systems, etc.

Yes, changes of venue, removal and remand are three of the key ways a case could move from one courthouse to another.
